# javascript matrix exponential, ala cv::Rodrigues( )?

Tags: javascript, math, webgl

Does anyone know of an existing code that does matrix exponential in javascript ?

Or, if not, what are "best practices" for writing something like that? I am used to C++ & Matlab, just trying my hand at hacking some WebGL stuff in the last few days ...

Comment: man !!! thats e^X, how is it supposed to be a power series ???

Comment: You might want to provide a link to [cv::Rodrigues()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#Rodrigues) as well as example math for people unfamiliar with the terminology.

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-rodrigues

Comment: I don't think someone unfamiliar with the terminology could answer, but more generally I could ask "what are best practices for writing efficient math utility functions in javascript"? Or, "what are suggested math libraries for javascript"? The cv rodrigues function is a shortcut in OpenCV for matrix exponential of a 3x3 skewsymmetric matrix.

Comment: @peter karasev: in this case this has nothing to do with computing a matrix exponential: this is asking for the rotation matrix around a given vector with a given angle, and there is a closed form formula for this. Henceforth, I delete my answer which is indeed useless (maybe you were the downvoter ?).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way , is to use quaternions math for intermediate rotation , so conversion will look
Rodrigues->quaternion->matrix
matrix->quaternion->Rodrigues

The quaternion->Rodrigues is trivial , and the matrix->quaternion implementation can be easy found.

Answer (score -1):

The closed form formula that you can implement yourself is there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Exponential_map